# Get the lines that have negative values on the 10th column using linux commands

Tags: regex, linux, file, command-line, grep

I need to get the lines that have negative values in the 10th column. To do this I would like to use command line tools, such as grep or sth else.

My file looks like this:

```
CUFF.258    CUFF.258    -   X:3346-3649 q1  q2  OK  1801.26 49.1276 -5.19633    3.04579 0.00232068  0.0343639   yes
CUFF.270    CUFF.270    -   X:785379-802854 q1  q2  OK  3452.95 15.4353 -7.80545    4.11536 3.86579e-05 0.00141746  yes
CUFF.291    CUFF.291    -   X:2035520-2038972   q1  q2  OK  40.6787 914.414 4.4905  -3.23369    0.00122202  0.0216311   yes
CUFF.303    CUFF.303    -   X:2608113-2614358   q1  q2  OK  263.583 18.2568 -3.85175    3.81319 0.000137187 0.00419976  yes
CUFF.304    CUFF.304    -   X:2813802-2818416   q1  q2  OK  0   352.966 1.79769e+308    1.79769e+308    0.000135079 0.00419976  yes
CUFF.315    CUFF.315    -   X:3286518-3342976   q1  q2  OK  475.812 19.775  -4.58864    3.38001 0.00072482  0.0144964   yes
CUFF.328    CUFF.328    -   X:4216658-4257029   q1  q2  OK  26.3907 664.784 4.65479 -3.98494    6.7498e-05  0.00221167  yes
CUFF.339    CUFF.339    -   X:4820540-4832077   q1  q2  OK  4993.62 130.117 -5.2622 4.48626 7.24836e-06 0.000384913 yes
CUFF.341    CUFF.341    -   X:4979865-5145183   q1  q2  OK  10.9841 109.543 3.31801 -3.00298    0.00267352  0.0381224   yes
CUFF.350    CUFF.350    -   X:5521697-5542510   q1  q2  OK  15.4241 263.2   4.0929  -3.32719    0.000877259 0.0167875   yes
```

I tried to do this using regular expressions with grep. But that way wasn't correct since I got some false positive lines.
I used `grep -e '-.\.'` to get negative values in general and that gave me lines from other columns. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: what are you counting as columns, characters, or "words"? I don't see negative values either at the 10 th character or column. Consider editing your question to a smaller data sample, (column3 for neg values), AND include expected output from that input. Finally, Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service, you're expected to show that you've tried to solve your problem with one tool or another. Based on your title, read up on `awk`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Yes thank you very much. I edited my question. If you know how to solve my problem using regular expression wildcards you are welcome to post your answer. As columns I am counting of course words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use awk:

```
awk '$10 < 0' yourfile
```

Comment: Clean and simple! Thank you, you are awesome!

Comment: Very nice... I always forget the power of `awk`

Answer (score 1):

I think this regex finds what you need: negative numbers in the tenth column, if the columns are space-separated.

```
/^(?:[^\s]+\s+){9}(\-[0-9\.]+)/m
```

Basically, it's a 9-repeating pattern of non-spaces, followed by exactly one hyphen (negative sign) and any number of digits and decimals... you can, of course, be more precise if necessary.

Edit: If you need to use this from the command line using `grep`, you would need to surround the regex with single quotes, and you can drop the `/` characters and multiline (`m`) option as those are defaults for grep'ing files:

```
~$ grep -P '^(?:[^\s]+\s+){9}(\-[0-9\.]+)' somefile.txt
```

Note that I've included the `-P` option here as this is a "Perl-style" regex.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what program (and flags) would you pass this regexp into. I tried something similar with grep, but I've always had trouble using grep with "modern/complex/python/javascript"-like regexps.